# How to generate Google-managed certificates for wildcard hostnames in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I would like to use Google-managed certificates for wildcard hostnames—for example, `*.example.com`.

I know I could use Certificate Manager from the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/deploy-google-managed-dns-auth#create_a_google-managed_certificate_referencing_the_dns_authorization) to do that in GCP, but I cannot find a concrete example.

Could you please show me some examples?

Comment: [Request a certificate using Certificate Manager Public CA](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/public-ca-tutorial)

Comment: Example terraform configs: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/11037#issuecomment-1362628852

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks @James' s answer. I also reference this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/deploy-google-managed-dns-auth#create_a_google-managed_certificate_referencing_the_dns_authorization).

I would like to post a concret example for this question in case anyone have the same doubts as me.

Most of the steps could reference to the doc, I would like to point out two steps you need to take care of.

In `Create a Google-managed certificate referencing the DNS authorization` step, provide your single domain and your wildcard hostname in the `--domains` options.

```bash
gcloud certificate-manager certificates create "my-cert" \
    --domains="example.com,*.example.com" \
    --dns-authorizations=my-dns-auth
```

In `Create a certificate map entry` step, create two entries for both single hostname and wildcard hostname.

```bash
gcloud certificate-manager maps entries create "my-entry1" \
    --map=my-map \
    --certificates=my-cert \
    --hostname="example.com"
```

```bash
gcloud certificate-manager maps entries create "my-entry2" \
    --map=my-map \
    --certificates=my-cert \
    --hostname="*.example.com"
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. This is life-saving information!!!

Comment: Some other notes would be that adding a certificate to a load balancer will remove any legacy ssl certs already attached. As such you'll need to recreate them add attach them with map-entries to the new cert you wish to attach.

Answer (score 2):

For your use case, it will be best to use `DNS authorization` since Load balancer authorization [does not support wildcard certificates](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/domain-authorization#:%7E:text=Load%20balancer%20authorization%20is%20faster%20to%20configure%20but%20does%20not%20support%20wildcard%20certificates). Each DNS authorization stores information about the DNS record that you need to set up and covers a single domain plus its wildcard—for example, example.com and *.example.com.

While this may not be a concrete example, this [document](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/deploy-google-managed-dns-auth) is a helpful guide in creating a Google-managed certificate with DNS authorization and its deployment to your Load Balancer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I also left my answer as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I created a wildcard certificate for a Google App Engine app. But my domain and DNS are managed by godaddy

I generated the certificate using CERTBOT. The important part here is the `--key-type` argument. Otherwise GAE will reject the certificate:

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --key-type rsa
```

This command generated 4 files. The ones that I used are the `fullchain.pem` and the `privkey.pem`. For the privkey I also changed the header and footer from this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
           <key>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

to this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
           <key>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And then I uploaded those files [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/certificates). For some reason the input for importing the private key did not work properly. I had to copy/past directly.

Comment: You cannot change `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` to `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`. They are two different DER encodings.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm just describing what I did. Without that change the Google Cloud UI does not let me upload the certificates. Perhaps its an error with the CERTBOT cli if I add the argument `--key-type RSA`. That header and footer should change.

Comment: RSA means different things in encryption, signing, certificates, and file formats. The term is used too often due to history.