# How to set up a wildcard cert with Google Load Balancer (GLB) using Pulumi

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, pulumi, wildcard-subdomain

I've been using certs with Google load balancers deployed with Pulumi but it seems the certificates need to be FQDN addresses and doesn't support wildcard subdomains. Ideally, if I could get example Pulumi code that would be great.

I tried searching for solutions but couldn't find any example code.

Comment: Always show your code and what you tried in your post so we can point out if you are using the wrong resource type or making other incorrect assumptions. You can use wildcard certificates with DNS challenge resolution (that means you are using Google DNS servers). https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/certificatemanager/certificate/

Comment: Hey John. Thanks for responding. I'm trying to get some initial rep so I posted my recent experience w/ answer after I was unable to find some example pulumi code on stackoverflow or google search. The pulumi link you provided didn't have a wildcard example so I hope my answer code will still be useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

after finding these articles

1. [How to generate Google-managed certificates for wildcard hostnames in GCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73734679/how-to-generate-google-managed-certificates-for-wildcard-hostnames-in-gcp)
2. https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/deploy-google-managed-dns-auth#gcloud

I was able to craft the equivalent Pulumi code as follows (Posting to share with others):

```
// DNS authorization cert
const ingressDnsAuthorization = new gcp.certificatemanager.DnsAuthorization(
  `prod-ingress-dns-auth`,
  {
    description: `prod wildcard ingress dns authorization`,
    domain: `foo-prod.exampledomain.com`, // root subdomain to be wildcard-ed
  }
);
export const ingressDnsAuth = ingressDnsAuthorization.dnsResourceRecords;
const ingressCert = new gcp.certificatemanager.Certificate(
  `prod-ingress-cert`,
  {
    description: `prod wildcard ingress cert`,
    scope: "DEFAULT",
    managed: {
      domains: [
        pulumi.interpolate`*.${ingressDnsAuthorization.domain}`, // wildcard subdomain
        ingressDnsAuthorization.domain, // root subdomain
      ],
      dnsAuthorizations: [ingressDnsAuthorization.id],
    },
  }
);
const ingressCertMap = new gcp.certificatemanager.CertificateMap(
  `prod-ingress-cert-map`,
  {
    description: `prod cert map`,
  }
);
const ingressCertMapEntry = new gcp.certificatemanager.CertificateMapEntry(
  `prod-ingress-cert-map-entry`,
  {
    description: `prod cert map entry`,
    map: ingressCertMap.name,
    certificates: [ingressCert.id],
    matcher: "PRIMARY",
  }
);

// ingress Https Proxy
const ingressHttpsProxy = new gcp.compute.TargetHttpsProxy(
  `prod-example-domain-ingress-https-proxy`,
  {
    urlMap: ingressLbUrlmap.id,
    certificateMap: pulumi.interpolate`//certificatemanager.googleapis.com/${ingressCertMap.id}`,
  }
);

// ingress GLB Fwd Rule (FrontEnd)
const ingressIP = new gcp.compute.GlobalAddress(
  `${env}-example-domain-ingress-lb-ip`,
  {}
);
const ingressGlbFwdRule = new gcp.compute.GlobalForwardingRule(
  `${env}-example-domain-ingress-glb-fwd-rule`,
  {
    target: ingressHttpsProxy.id,
    portRange: "443",
    ipAddress: ingressIP.address,
    ipProtocol: "TCP",
    loadBalancingScheme: "EXTERNAL",
  }
);
```